# How to determine is an object is a structure? No "GetType(Object).IsStructure function

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking for a similar "IsStructure" function. Is there some other way to determine if T is a structure but not an intrinsic type?

```
Public Shared Function MySub(Of TData)(ByVal t As TData) As TData
    Dim IsClass As Boolean
    IsClass = GetType(TData).IsClass
End Function
```

Note that using IsPrimitive and IsValueType on Nullable(Of Integer) and a Structure returns the same results, False and True, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Type.IsValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx) and [Type.IsPrimitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) should do the trick for you.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking into that but "Nullable (Of Integer)" returns "False" for IsPrimitive and True for IsValueType, which is the same as what I would get when testing a Structure type, but Nullable (Of Integer) is not a Structure.

Comment: Why is it not a structure? Nullable<T> is defined as a struct.

Comment: My mistake. You are correct. You answered the question. But I was really trying to distinguish between a NULLABLE (Of Primitive) and a Structure. I think I can use this to make the distinction: "Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(GetType(TData)) Is Nothing"

Answer (score 0):

.IsClass

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isclass.aspx

.IsValueType

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isvaluetype.aspx

Edit -

Short Linqpad program:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();

    a.GetType().IsValueType.Dump("class IsValueType");
    a.GetType().IsClass.Dump("class IsClasse");
    a.GetType().IsPrimitive.Dump("class IsPrimitive");

    b.GetType().IsValueType.Dump("struct IsValueType");
    b.GetType().IsClass.Dump("struct IsClasse");
    b.GetType().IsPrimitive.Dump("struct IsPrimitive");
}

class A{}
struct B{}
```

Results

```
class IsValueType

False


class IsClasse

True


class IsPrimitive

False


struct IsValueType

True


struct IsClasse

False


struct IsPrimitive

False
```